# What is the recommended way to show db query results on every page (badge notification)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show the number of items linked to my user as a badge next to the menu on the top of my asp.net MVC page. (I am using bootstrap 3)

Because I don't want this to be static i.e. it must dynamically update I put it in a partial view page _Menu.cshtml that is referenced in my Layout page which is called with every page load

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li>@*Html.ActionLink("Proposals", "Index", "MyController")*@
        @{
            var db = new MyDb();
            var count = db.Proposals.Count(p => p.UserName== User.Identity.Name );
            db.Dispose();
        }
        <a href="/MyController/Index">Home <span class="badge pull-right">@count</span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So it can appear on every page

I don't think this is very good way because

1) Separation of concerns. I have db logic directly in my cshtml

2) Calling it on every page is not so good idea but I am not sure of the best way to still refresh it but somehow cache it

What is the best practice for menu badge notification in asp.net MVC for the above scenario?

Comment: use Child Action Methodes : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18561334/is-there-any-way-to-create-special-controller-for-my-layout

Comment: In your controller add it to your `ViewData` collection.

Comment: Hi Sirwan I tried that and put @{ Html.RenderAction("GetNumberOfOpenProposals", "MyCOntroller");} in the partial _Menu.cshtml page. This results in a error when loading the page that says I need a GetNumberOfOpenProposals.cshtml. Is there any way I can not have this new page as I just want the single count value in my partial menu view. Is it possible to have actionmethod return a value to my partial view menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of ways you may get it work. Your way is not recommended in MVC.

You may use `ViewData`, `PartialView` or `jQuery`.

Add action method to your controller:

```
public ActionResult GetCount()
{
var db = new MyDb();
var count = db.Proposals.Count(p => p.UserName== User.Identity.Name );
db.Dispose();
return PartialView(count )
}
```

In your `GetCount()` PartialView:

```
<a href="/Buyer/Index">Home <span class="badge pull-right">@Model</span></a>
```

In your _Menu.cshtm if using PartialView:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Proposals", "Index", "MyController")
        @{Html.RenderAction("GetCount", "Home")}
    </li>
</ul>
```

In your `_Menu.cshtm` if using `jQuery`:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Proposals", "Index", "MyController")
     <div class="Count"></div>
        @{Html.RenderAction("GetCount", "Home")}
    </li>
</ul>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".Count").load('@Url.Action("GetCount", "Home")')
});

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer, It is what I am looking for. Just a question. I added PartialView("_Menu",numberOfProposals); in the actionmethod seeing the partialview naming standard is to start the naming with an underscore as I understand or should I handle it as an naming convention exception seeing it has its own actionmethod so isn't exactly like a partial page?